# Subview Constraints breaking Parent Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I'm making a custom tab view that autosizes based on constraints and I'm having a problem when I try to add subviews to it which also use constraints.

If I add a subview and give it constraints, like this for example:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

[super awakeFromNib];

UIBlurEffect* blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
background = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blur];

NSLayoutConstraint* topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:background
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                multiplier:1
                                                                  constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint* leadConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:background
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 multiplier:1
                                                                   constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint* trailConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:background
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:self
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                  multiplier:1
                                                                    constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint* botConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:background
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                multiplier:1
                                                                  constant:0];
[background setFrame:self.bounds];
[self addSubview:background];
[self addConstraints:@[topConstraint, leadConstraint, trailConstraint, botConstraint]];

}
```

The tab view will no longer respond to constraints. If I add the tab view to a storyboard and try to set constraints on it, it just doesn't respond. I can manually resize it to make it fit the constraints, but it won't do it automatically, and changing the device will of course, break the constraints.

[image]

Removing this line which adds the constraints fixes the problem, but I want the subviews to resize automatically based on the constraints.

```
//[self addConstraints:@[topConstraint, leadConstraint, trailConstraint, botConstraint]];
```

Is this possible, or do I just have to make the view resize all of its subviews when ever a layout update is called?

Comment: `background.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` before you `addConstraints`?

Answer (score 0):

As @DonMag said, background.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; maybe a correct answer.

Or you can try remove addConstraints, and use topConstraint.active = YES, etc.